# Why is this function name causing “Invalid function” when in a list for `dolist`?

Tags: quote

How can I **use `dolist` to repeat an operation** for each item in a list?

I have a sequence of statements:

```lisp
(put 'downcase-region 'disabled nil)
(put 'upcase-region 'disabled nil)
(put 'narrow-to-defun 'disabled nil)
(put 'narrow-to-region 'disabled nil)
(put 'narrow-to-page 'disabled nil)
(put 'set-goal-column 'disabled nil)
```

that I want to re-factor by putting each name into a list, then repeating the operation for each name.

So I think [the `dolist` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/dolist.html) can achieve this.

This fails:

```lisp
(dolist (command
  (
   'downcase-region
   'upcase-region
   'narrow-to-defun
   'narrow-to-region
   'narrow-to-page
   'set-goal-column
   )
  (put command 'disabled nil)))
```

with an error

> Invalid function: 'downcase-region

Why is that an “invalid function” in one instance but not the other?

How should that `dolist` be written to achieve the same effect as the first example?

Comment: a package named `elisp-demos` helps you with such kind of questions. [Here is the entry of dolist](https://github.com/xuchunyang/elisp-demos/blob/master/elisp-demos.org#dolist)

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call random function from list](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68246/call-random-function-from-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> an error
>
> > Invalid function: 'downcase-region
>
> Why is that an “invalid function” in one instance but not the other?

The error is complaining that it's been asked to *invoke* a function, named `'downcase-region`.

This is because the list `('downcase-region 'upcase-region 'narrow-to-defun …)` is evaluated immediately; which attempts to invoke a function named `'downcase-region`. Which doesn't exist.

Instead of evaluating the list immediately, the list needs to survive as-is as a *value* for the `dolist` function. You do this by quoting the list.

```lisp
(dolist (command
  '(downcase-region
    upcase-region
    narrow-to-defun
    narrow-to-region
    narrow-to-page
    set-goal-column
    ))
  (put command 'disabled nil))
```

Comment: Almost, you should drop the inner quotes. And you're missing a close parenthesis.

Comment: I've fixed those problems.

Comment: @bignose: Re: your "format code more readably" edit -- if you're *not* using the standard indentation that Emacs gives you, you're (a) going to unnecessary effort; and (b) going to end up with code that *no one else* finds readable.  I strongly recommend you simply get accustomed to how everyone else (and Emacs) formats lisp -- you will consider it readable soon enough.